# Using a hashtable while building a lexical analyser

Tags: c, compiler-construction, lexer

I'm building a lexical analyser for a compiler, and I'm using hashing to recoginse keywords quickly.

My hashing function is :

```
int Eval_Hash(char *str)
{       
    int prime = 5381;
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
    prime = (prime*33) + str[i];

        return (abs(prime%(KeyWordCount*KeyWordCount)));
}
```

I'm hashing the keywords using the following code snippet.

```
    i = 0;
    while(i < KeyWordCount) {
            while(1)
                {   
                    tmp = (Eval_Hash(keywordList[i])+j*j)%(KeyWordCount*KeyWordCount);
                    if(h.Elem[tmp].hashVal == INT_MIN)
                    {
                        strcpy(h.Elem[tmp].name,tokenList[i]);
                        h.Elem[tmp].hashVal = tmp;
                        strcpy(h.Elem[tmp].value,keywordList[i]);
                        break;
                    }
                j++;
                }   
            i++;
        }
```

But when I'm doing the lexical analysis, the lexemes from the input stream are getting hashed into different slots. For example, say, 'parameters' is a keyword, which has already been hashed while initializing the hashtable. But when I read a 'parameters' from the input stream, it's getting recognized as some other token.

The code snippet to hash a string from the input stream is as follows:

```
                Hash_Value = Eval_Hash(str);
            printf("\n  \n Hash Value: %d Modified Hash Value: %d \n \n ",Hash_Value,Hash_Value%(KeyWordCount*KeyWordCount));
            count = 1;
            for(j=0;count<KeyWordCount;j++)
            {
                tmp = (Hash_Value+j*j)%(KeyWordCount*KeyWordCount);
                if(h.Elem[tmp].flag == 1)
                    count++;

                else if(strcmp(h.Elem[tmp].value, str) == 0)
                {
                    alpha_flag = 1;
                    h.Elem[tmp].flag = 1;
                    strcpy(token->name,h.Elem[tmp].name);
                    break;
                }
                else
                    h.Elem[tmp].flag = 1;
}
```

Moreover the typedefs for the hashtable are

```
struct _hashElem {
    int hashVal;
    int flag;
    char name[30];//keyw
    char value[30];
};

typedef struct _hashElem hashElem;

struct _Hash {
    hashElem Elem[KeyWordCount*KeyWordCount];
};

typedef struct _Hash Hash;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just a sidenote, you already do modulo with `(KeyWordCount*KeyWordCount)` inside the hash function, no need to do it again outside.

Comment: You don't check for collisions... What if two different words have the same hash value?

Comment: Side Note: I hope you're using > 32bit signed `int` types for this. otherwise are you *counting* on integer overflow. Ex. the word "parameters", having 10 chars will execute `prime=prime*33+str[i]` 10 times. This accumulation is lower-bound by `prime * (33^10)`, which is 5381*1531578985264449, considerably outside the signed int ceiling of 2147483647.

Comment: As has already been mentioned in the comments - you don't check for collisions. Since you're hashing keywords only you must know them all ahead of time? If that is so you could use a perfect hash function thus removing the risk of collisions (and probably making it quicker into the bargain). GPerf springs to mind.

  [1]: http://www.gnu.org/software/gperf

Answer (score -4):

This is a waste of your time. In this day and age, or indeed in any day and age after about 1988 when it first appeared, you should be using flex to be generating the lexer, and you should let it recognize the keywords, just by specifying them separately as rules. It can do that just as quickly as recognizing general identifiers. No hash table required at all.

Comment: @lesmana The original name was indeed 'flex', but that has since been taken over by something else. See the tag wiki for example.

Comment: I am aware of the ambiguity around the name and tag "flex". See here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86933/rename-gnu-flex-to-flex-lexer

Comment: I'm getting curious about these unexplained downvotes. I've done what's described here many times.

Comment: Because it might always be for learning purposes? ( And I think there's some other reaons one might hand code it! )

Comment: "By replacing the lex-generated scanner used in the first version by a hand-written one, we almost doubled the speed of the Lua compiler on typical metafiles." [The Evolution of Lua (**PDF**)](http://www.lua.org/doc/hopl.pdf)

Comment: @porkshoulder Frankly I find that hard to believe. The Lua compiler must have nothing else to do if its speed can be so radically altered. Even if true, compilation speed hasn't been a significant  issue for many years. And even if that's an issue, the OP should certainly start with a generated scanner and get on with the rest of his compiler, and revisit it later if performance should prove to be inadequate.

Comment: @Christian I do not understand what your first comment refers to, and if you have other reasons in mind please state them.